# Codeigniter 2.1.3 install issue after moving app and system folders

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation

Ive decided to try a framework since my project is getting big and settled on Codeigniter 2.1.3. It works as expected with the default folder setup, but I am getting the CI 404 page after I move the Application and System folders up one level like:

```
/Application/
/System/
/www/index.php
```

I changed $system_path to '../system' and $application_folder to '../application' (I also tried absolute paths) like the documentation states. I have traced the issue in CodeIgniter.php to:

```
if (method_exists($CI, '_remap'))
```

and it seems this is returning false. I can do a print_r on $CI but I'm not sure what I am looking for or where to debug from here and I'm looking for guidance. I have no other experience with frameworks.

Also, it may be relevant that my server is setup with this app needing to be shared by two virtual hosts. folders setup like:

```
c:/server/web/domain1.com/www
c:/server/web/domain2.com/www
c:/server/web/myapp/www
```

so in each virtual host I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/myapp(.*)$ c:/server/web/myapp/www/$1
```

so that domain1.com/myapp and domain2.com/myapp both take you to myapp.

please let me know what other information if any I can provide
Thanks for reading and trying to help.

Comment: I had some funky errors like that on some server setup, I had system folder up 2 levels (../../system), but had to set it to (../system) for CI to work, I don't know the reason behind that, but you can always try

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Novice framework user mistake. It was a problem with a path in a controller. I'm sorry for wasting anybody's time.